# Manipulate array of objects to new array with average number.

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a array that I want to manipulate because I need to use it as a datasource for D3.js. An example of this dataset would be:

```
var data =  [
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 100,  year: 2010},
 {day: 2, month: 1,  length: 125,  year: 2010},
 {day: 3, month: 1,  length: 150,  year: 2010},
 {day: 4, month: 1,  length: 175,  year: 2010},
 {day: 1, month: 2,  length: 225,  year: 2010},
 {day: 2, month: 2,  length: 250,  year: 2010},
 {day: 3, month: 2,  length: 325,  year: 2010},

 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 225,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 150,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 190,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 2,  length: 210,  year: 2011},
 {day: 2, month: 2,  length: 110,  year: 2011},
 {day: 3, month: 2,  length: 160,  year: 2011},
 {day: 4, month: 2,  length: 190,  year: 2011},
]
```

In this case I want to create a new array, with two arrays that hold the average length of a month. For example:

```
var newData = [ [137.5, 266.7], [183.33, 167.5] ]
```

Where newData[0][1] would be the average length of month 1 in year 2010.

I have some problems incorporating this in a nice way. I can create the sum of the length, but dividing the sum is difficult. The code I have is:

```
data.forEach(function (el) {
   for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
     if (el.year === 2010 + j) {
       for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                if (el.month === i) {
                    var oldLength = dataNew[j][i - 1] || 0;
                    var newLength = el.length + oldLength;
                    dataNew[j][i - 1] = newLength;
                }
        }
     }
   }
});
```

How would this function could be adjusted so it saves the average instead of the sum in newData.

Comment: So the `day` component of the original data doesn’t matter? Is the input data always “sorted” by month and year? Where does the input data come from (can maybe that part be modified to deliver the needed format right away)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use d3.js itself for facilitate you job and make your code more readable. Using `d3.nest()`

```
var data =  [
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 100,  year: 2010},
 {day: 2, month: 1,  length: 125,  year: 2010},
 {day: 3, month: 1,  length: 150,  year: 2010},
 {day: 4, month: 1,  length: 175,  year: 2010},
 {day: 1, month: 2,  length: 225,  year: 2010},
 {day: 2, month: 2,  length: 250,  year: 2010},
 {day: 3, month: 2,  length: 325,  year: 2010},

 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 225,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 150,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 1,  length: 190,  year: 2011},
 {day: 1, month: 2,  length: 210,  year: 2011},
 {day: 2, month: 2,  length: 110,  year: 2011},
 {day: 3, month: 2,  length: 160,  year: 2011},
 {day: 4, month: 2,  length: 190,  year: 2011},
]

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.year})
    .key(function(d){return d.month})
    .rollup(function(d){
        return d3.mean(d, function(g){return g.length});
    })
    .entries(data)

console.log(nest[0].values[0]) // 137.5
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9nva3h9/)

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't aware of the nest() function. Thanks. This is going to be very useful when I have to work with other datasets.